# ruby api has_many syntax # sign

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax, has-many

In the ruby API, the examples for has_many associations are

Example: A Firm class declares has_many :clients, which will add:

```
Firm#clients (similar to Clients.find :all, :conditions => ["firm_id = ?", id])
Firm#clients<<
Firm#clients.delete
Firm#clients=
Firm#client_ids
```

why arn't the methods firm.clients, firm.clients<< etc.. what does the # sign mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it were written like `Firm.clients`, then it would mean it's a method call on `Firm`, not on instances of it. If there is a particular instance `firm` on which you want to call the method, you can write `firm.clients`. One purpose of an API is to show what methods are available on any instance of a class. `Firm#clients` means a method call of `clients` on an arbitrary instance of `Firm`. `#` used in this way is not part of Ruby syntax, but is an established convention.

Answer (score 3):

This syntax is documentation syntax indicating that it is an Instance Method, not a method on the class.

The `Array#sort` indicates that there is a `sort` method available for instances of `Array`.

If it shows `Array.new`, then that indicates that it is a method on the `Array` class itself.

It is only there for our benefit, not Ruby's parser.